# Contradiction on jump conditions.

Tags: potential, maxwell-equations

Just a picture of my configuration.

[image]

The assumption here is $\epsilon_a,\epsilon_b,\epsilon_c$ are different from one another. Really the interest of this problem is to find the scalar potential $\phi$, such that $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$.

So now my question, about jump conditions, 
Surface at $y=0$ has tangent $\vec{E}$ continous, thus 
$\begin{align} 
-\hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_a =  -\hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_b \\
-\hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_a =  -\hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_c \\
\end{align}$

However if we look at $x=0$ then normal $\vec{D}$ is continous thus

$\begin{align} 
-\epsilon_b \hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_b =  - \epsilon_c \hat{x} \cdot \nabla \phi_c \\
\end{align}$

From our relation above this implies that $\epsilon_b=\epsilon_c$, which we made no such assumption. So this looks like a contradiction to me.

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Thank you!